# Javascript always run a function on the longest array, and use the shortest inside that function

Tags: javascript

The following function should always compare all the items in the longest array and see if they exist in the shorter one.

Now the following code works, but it's a bit verbose.

```js
const findSimilar = (arr1, arr2) => {
  const arrLongest = (arr1.length < arr2.length) ? arr2 : arr1;
  const arrShortest = (arr1.length < arr2.length) ? arr1 : arr2;
  return arrLongest.filter((arrLongestItem) => arrShortest.includes(arrLongestItem));
};

console.log(findSimilar([1,2,3,4,3], [1,2,3])); // (3) [1, 2, 3, 3]
console.log(findSimilar([1,2,3], [1,2,3,4,3])); // (4) [1, 2, 3, 3]
```

Is it necessary to have the two variables `arrLongest` and `arrShortest`? Or is there another way.

Comment: `if (a.length < b.length) [a, b] = [b, a]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the conditional operator just once and then destructure into the two variables for the arrays:

```js
const findSimilar = (arr1, arr2) => {
  const [arrLongest, arrShortest] = (arr1.length < arr2.length) ? [arr2, arr1] : [arr1, arr2];
  return arrLongest.filter((arrLongestItem) => arrShortest.includes(arrLongestItem));
};

console.log(findSimilar([1,2,3,4,3], [1,2,3])); // (3) [1, 2, 3, 3]
console.log(findSimilar([1,2,3], [1,2,3,4,3])); // (4) [1, 2, 3, 3]
```

To reduce the computational complexity from `O(n^2)` to `O(n)`, use a Set instead, for the shortest array:

```js
const findSimilar = (arr1, arr2) => {
  const [arrLongest, arrShortest] = (arr1.length < arr2.length) ? [arr2, arr1] : [arr1, arr2];
  const shortSet = new Set(arrShortest);
  return arrLongest.filter(shortSet.has, shortSet);
};

console.log(findSimilar([1,2,3,4,3], [1,2,3])); // (3) [1, 2, 3, 3]
console.log(findSimilar([1,2,3], [1,2,3,4,3])); // (4) [1, 2, 3, 3]
```

Comment: Very nice to include the suggestion to include the computational complexity! Will mark this answer as accepted when the default time has expired.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to write it would be to use `sort` and destructing.

And reuse the existing parameters:

```js
const findSimilar = (arr1, arr2) => {
  [arr1, arr2] = [arr1, arr2].sort((a, b) => a.length - b.length)
  return arr2.filter((arrLongestItem) => arr1.includes(arrLongestItem));
};
```

Or stay with `arrShortest` and `arrLongest` as it would be more verbose what the variable exactly contains.

```js
const findSimilar = (arr1, arr2) => {
  const [arrShortest, arrLongest] = [arr1, arr2].sort((a, b) => a.length - b.length)
  return arrShortest.filter((arrLongestItem) => arrLongest.includes(arrLongestItem));
};
```

I would always preferre additional variables that are correctly named over reusing variable names.

The advantage of using `sort` is that it expresses what is done, and you reduce the possible errors as `arr1`, `arr2` are used only once in the expression, instead of three times like in the `?:`

And you for sure can combine it with `new Set` in the answer of [CertainPerformance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59233931/1960455)

Comment: @Remi I'm not sure why people (I keep catching me doing it, too) try to shorten code jamming it in one line, and reusing variables, just for the sake of some saved space. Just to look on it months later not understanding what the heck it does. The main aim is to make your code readable and maintainable, and that includes giving variables meaning full names. And if `(arr1.length < arr2.length) ? [arr2, arr1] : [arr1, arr2]` is noticeable faster then `[arr1, arr2].sort((a, b) => a.length - b.length)`  then it could be a good idea to wrap the `?:` in a helper function with a good name.

Comment: Definitely! Thanks for the advice. I try to make it as readable as possible. I don't know which one is faster of the two. Will do some research. I guess you're saying that the ternary is less readable?

Comment: @Remi not all the time, but it can. With `const [arrLongest, arrShortest] = … ? … : …` you know what to expect from the ternary because of the naming of the variables, so it immediately becomes easier to read. For `[arr1, arr2] = … ? … : …` you don't know what to expect so the ternary wouldn't be that easy to read and it would be better to wrap it in a function. (The same is also true for the `sort` based expression, but the `sort` itself also give an initial hint what it does)